# Error al enviar msj con bot telegram en python

Tags: python, python-requests, telegram, telegram-bot

quiero enviar un msj a un canal con un bot de telegram. Le envio por post el msj pero no lo envia, me da error 400

```
import request

request = requests.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendMessage',
data = {'chat_id' : '@r00tChannel', 'text' : 'Hola'})

print(request)
```

<Response [400]>

alguien sabe donde puede estar el error

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido stack overflow!, no sé si al colocar el url cambiaste el token intencionalmente pero normalmente en donde va "bot<TOKEN>" va el token del bot en cuestión